# Solution for Spark Plan Growing too Large and Job Erroring out

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My Spark/Scala job is processing data in a loop. I need to use the result of the previous loop to process information. I was caching the results, but the issue is that the spark plan for the cached DataFrame grows too large and my job errors out. While I have found a back up solution of writing to and reading from S3, it is time consuming. So, if there is a way to utilize the cache without growing the spark plan I would like to try it out. Or if there is another way to keep track of the computed data within the Spark program that would also help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Dataset.checkpoint()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#checkpoint--) method at the end of each iteration.

It will persist your current RDD state and truncate the plan.

You need to manually set a checkpoint directory before hand using SparkContext.setCheckpointDir(), since it's unset by default.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase the spark.driver.memory to a value that is more than the size of the plan